# Oozie 4.0.1 build error while using Hadoop 2.4.1

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, oozie, hcatalog

I was trying to build Oozie 4.0.1 on Hadoop 2.4.1 with centOS 6.5 using the command

```
bin/mkdistro.sh -P hadoop-2 -DskipTests
```

The build fails at this point

```
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main .................................. SUCCESS [  0.688 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ................................ SUCCESS [ 24.719 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 .............. SUCCESS [  0.431 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ....... SUCCESS [  0.035 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 Test ......... SUCCESS [  0.065 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 .............. SUCCESS [  1.626 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 Test ......... SUCCESS [  0.098 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ....... SUCCESS [  0.038 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [  1.176 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [  0.087 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [  0.028 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs ........................... SUCCESS [  1.493 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.1 .............. SUCCESS [  0.148 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ............................ SUCCESS [  0.319 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............ FAILURE [  0.127 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.826 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-02T21:17:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/358M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hcatalog:jar:0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:0.5.0-incubating -> org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0-incubating -> org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.10.0 -> org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:jar:2.0.3 -> asm:asm:jar:[3.0, 4.0): No versions available for asm:asm:jar:[3.0, 4.0) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

the repository links that I have tried are the following:

```
<url>https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/ext-release-local/</url>      
<url>http://121.241.113.72:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
<url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo</url> 
<url>https://github.com/CeON/oozie-maven-plugin</url>
<url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
<url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
<url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
```

But all resulted in the same error, and the distro creation process fails at that particular point only.
For hadoop 2.4.1 I have also changed the required POM entries.

```
cd hadooplibs
File hadoop-2/pom.xml : change hadoop-client & hadoop-auth dependency version to 2.4.1
File hadoop-distcp-2/pom.xml: change hadoop-distcp version to 2.4.1
File hadoop-test-2/pom.xml: change hadoop-minicluster version to 2.4.1
```

And in the main Oozie POM file this

> ```
>         <profile>
>             <id>hadoop-2</id>
>             <activation>
>                 <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
>             </activation>
>             <properties>
>                <hadoop.version>2.4.1</hadoop.version>
>                <hadoop.auth.version>2.4.1</hadoop.auth.version>
>                <pig.classifier>h2</pig.classifier>
>                <sqoop.classifier>hadoop200</sqoop.classifier>
>             </properties>
>         </profile>
> ```

Please tell me a way to install this Oozie 4.0.1 with Hadoop 2.4.1  **Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: did you solve this? I am also facing the same issue. it looks like the latest oozie-hadoop jar available in the repo is 2.3,

Comment: Nops. 
I am still stuck at it.

Comment: @Mb-One any update on this? i am also facing the same issue? Hadoop version which i am using is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link below to build the oozie 4.1.0.

http://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/

Its working finely . am using the build for hadoop 2.6.0

Comment: what is the repo url? i am not seeing oozie-hadoop jar higher than 2.3 in the default repo. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22oozie-hadoop%22

Comment: @karthik : I followed the same website earlier but all in vain. Got stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am using Oozie-4.0.1 with Hadoop 2.3.0

I had a similar error.

```
...
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.1 .............. SUCCESS [  0.172 s]
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ............................ SUCCESS [  0.530 s]
    [INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............ FAILURE [  0.436 s]
    [INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog .................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 32.522 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-11T12:58:10-05:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 44M/643M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hcatalog:jar:0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failed to coll
    ect dependencies at org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:0.5.0-incubating -> org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0-incubating -> org.apache.hive:hive-
    builtins:jar:0.10.0 -> org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:0.10.0 -> org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.10.0 -> javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec: Failed to read artifact descrip
    tor for javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec: Could not transfer artifact javax.jdo:jdo2-api:pom:2.3-ec from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository
    .codehaus.org: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]
```

I was able to fix it by removing codehause.org repository from base pom.xml entirely since "All Codehaus services have now been terminated." as stated on http://www.codehaus.org/

remove following lines from pom.xml

```
<repository>
      <id>Codehaus repository</id> 
      <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url> 
      <snapshots> <enabled>false</enabled> </snapshots>
 </repository>
```